# Keyboard Issues After Resuming From Sleep on a Dell Vostro 13

Tags: keyboard, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 x64.  It's running on my Dell Vostro V13.  Everything works great until I shut the lid of my laptop (puts laptop into sleep).  Once I come back and resume working in Ubuntu, typing becomes a chore.  Ubuntu misses a lot of the keypresses from my keyboard.  It usually results in me mashing my keyboard until the letter appears.  A full system reboot fixes the problem.  Again, typing is never an issue unless I resume from sleep.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to 12.10 seems to solve the problem.

For 12.04 and below:

As a temporary fix you can use/try this solution:

```
 sudo modprobe -r psmouse   
 sudo modprobe psmouse
```

I saw it here: [Touchpad stops working after suspend on a Clevo M55N](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89324/touchpad-stops-working-after-suspend-on-a-clevo-m55n) and it worked for me!

Now on ubuntu 12.04, I am still using the temporary fix i found and posted earlier and it works. But when i created a script that runs the two commands - it didn't work! i noticed i had to add "sleep 2" between the commands for the script fix to function.

Comment: Did this solve the problem with the keyboard?