# Keyboard starts skipping characters after wake from suspension/sleep, restart required.

Tags: keyboard, suspend, sleep

After my computer wakes from sleep the keyboard is starting to skip characters unless i type very very slow. The only solution i have found is to restart the computer.

Being linux i guess there most be a quicker way to fix this error, maybe by restarting the service that is handling the input or something similar that will save me time instead of doing a reboot.

Computer is an Dell Vostro v13 with ubuntu 12.10 if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by running:

> sudo modprobe -r psmouse
>
> sudo modprobe psmouse

so i put it in a script and placed it in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ and named it 20_keyboardquickfix

```
#!/bin/sh
#put it in /etc/pm/sleep.d/ and name it 20_keyboardquickfix
#make sure it is runnable. by running "sudo chmod 755 20_keyboardquickfix"

#this scipts removes and then inserts the module psmouse, this is a #quick fix for keyboard working strangely after wakeup from sleep
#solution was found on askubuntu:
#http://askubuntu.com/questions/77143/keyboard-issues-after-resuming-from-sleep-on-a-dell-vostro-13?rq=1

modprobe -r psmouse
sleep 3
modprobe psmouse
```

Comment: Any other ideas? I have the same problem, but this doesn't work.